# Problema com XPATH

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Olá, sou novo em programação e estou tentando fazer uma automação, para realizar pagamentos.

Quando eu rodo o código:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
servico = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
navegador = webdriver.Chrome(service=servico)
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
navegador.get('http://sigef.sefin.ro.gov.br/sigef/SIGEFPortal.html?p=1')
navegador.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/form/table[3]/tbody/tr/td/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[3]/span/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/input').send_keys("00001")
```

Ele me retorna o seguinte erro:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/form/table[3]/tbody/tr/td/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[3]/span/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/input"}
```

Não é problema de tempo. Acredito que seja algo relacionado a frame.

O html é este:

```
<input name="txtCdGestao$SIGEFPesquisa" type="text" maxlength="5" id="txtCdGestao_SIGEFPesquisa" class="SIGEFPesquisa" onmouseout="window.status=' '" onpaste="javascript: return false;" oncontextmenu="javascript: return false;" onblur="javascript: return FormatarValorNumerico(this, event, '99999');" onkeypress="javascript: return ValidarDigito(this, event, '99999');" onfocus="javascript:RemoverZerosEsquerda(this, event, '99999');" ondragenter="javascript: return false;" onkeydown="javascript:PesquisarLimparToolTip('txtCdGestao_SIGEFPesquisa', 'txtCdGestao_hdn_tooltip', event);" onmouseover="window.status='Informe a Unidade Gestora e Gestão';return true" style="color:Black;width:50px;text-align:left;" title="">
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Não duplique perguntas, restaure a pergunta original e edite-a seguindo as [orientações dadas](/questions/589749/problema-com-xpath#comment1026280_589749). Comentários foram bloqueados nessa postagem, se precisar comentar algo relacionado ao problema faça-o na pergunta original.